# Can changing iPad motherboard to older version bypass iCloud lock?

Tags: ipad

I was curious to know if its possible to change the motherboard of an iPad to reset its software version? The iPad is locked to my friends late grandpa, and hence locked to his name.

I was using it without any problems until one fine day when the iOS upgraded from 6.0 to 7.0 and after that it was asking the iCloud password of the device, which unfortunately none of us knows. Then I kept the iPad as a decoration, until today, when it struck me, that probably changing the motherboard might help to reset the software version to an earlier iOS version.

Or are there any other possible technical solution to bring back the iPad to life, instead of running around solicitors and lawyers?

This is a genuinely bought family iPad / not stolen etc duly passed on to a family member.

Comment: @SteveChambers too much work and paper.. I already spent hours talking to them without any success. I would rather like to have some technical solution for this problem, rather than running behind some unknown support guy.

Comment: It’s not worth going through that process for an iPad of that age, your best bet is buying a new iPad.

Comment: @Do2 I thought SE was more of a question and answer site.. Instead I see that there are so many opinions here !

Comment: The trouble with [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/222623) questions is that they insight alternative answers which don't answer your actual question. It's perfectly understandable to face a problem, try to solve it, then have a question about *your* idea on that possible solution, but many people who come here ‘get stuck’ down another path rather than considering the bigger picture. I hope by narrowing the title to the problem you will receive more insightful answers specific to your proposed solution, but keep the XY problem balance in mind.

Comment: See the answer by @duskwuff below. Changing the motherboard will not have the desired effect of giving you access to the info currently on the iPad. Failing a hacking tool that bypasses any of Apple's security, you don't have much choice in the matter. Unfortunate but true.

Comment: @SteveChambers - I didnt want to access the info on the iPad. I wanted to set it as a new IPad. So, I guess, its possible to buy a clean motherboard and replace it. Since the apple security chip comes on the motherboard, I think its possible to boot the iPad as a brand new iPad. But I still didnt try it.

Answer (score 3):

For most intents and purposes, the motherboard *is* the iPad. The rest of it is just parts which surround the motherboard -- case, battery, screen, *etc*.

All of the device's storage is on the motherboard -- placing a new motherboard into the shell of another iPad will not give you access to data which was stored on the old iPad, because the storage was all on the motherboard you removed.

If your goal is simply to have a working device, you can continue, of course. But if you want to get access to the data you had on the old iPad, you'll want to look into other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you can do it does not mean that you should.

Can you bypass iCloud lock by installing a clean motherboard? yes.

Should you do it? no. It will probably be the same price, maybe cheaper, to buy another ipad and you will not have the risk of messing something up during installation.

Comment: thanks .. what is a "clean" motherboard?

Comment: @infoclogged One that didn't come out of another iCloud-locked device.

Answer (score 2):

> I have heard that if you can provide an official certificate of death, to Apple they will reset passwords of systems/accounts belonging to the deceased. That said a third party repair shop will likely be able to do this for you.

–From comment by Steve Chambers

Comment: I think you still need the original purchase receipt.